Avoid full cross-join in testing each record against every other record
The merge in pandas has a cross-join function.  I was hoping to
avoid a full cross-join in pairing each record of a large dataframe
with upto (say) a dozen records in another dataframe (possibly the
same dataframe) based on complex criteria involving a function of
multiple fields, i.e., not necessarily an equivalence relationship between
"key" columns.
Below is one simple example of matching based on inequality
relationships.  I've commented out some input records to make the
output smaller, but they can be easily added back in for
experimentation with stricter matching criteria:
import pandas as pd

# Input dataframe
df_in = pd.DataFrame([ [ 1, 1, 4, 1 ],
                       [ 3, 4, 2, 4 ],
                       [ 0, 2, 0, 0 ],
                       [ 3, 1, 4, 4 ],
                       [ 0, 4, 4, 3 ],
#                      [ 1, 4, 2, 2 ],
#                      [ 3, 2, 0, 2 ],
#                      [ 3, 3, 1, 1 ],
#                      [ 0, 2, 2, 2 ],
#                      [ 4, 1, 2, 4 ],
#                      [ 3, 1, 1, 2 ],
#                      [ 2, 2, 3, 2 ],
#                      [ 2, 1, 3, 1 ],
#                      [ 2, 4, 1, 2 ],
#                      [ 1, 0, 0, 3 ],
                       [ 2, 1, 1, 3 ],
                       [ 2, 0, 1, 1 ],
                       [ 4, 1, 2, 1 ],
                       [ 3, 2, 2, 4 ],
                       [ 3, 1, 0, 0 ] ],
               columns=['A','B','C','D'] )

# Full cross-join
df_out = df_in.merge( df_in, how='cross' )

# Select a very small subset
df_out = df_out[ ( df_out.A_x < df_out.B_y ) &
                 ( df_out.C_x > df_out.D_y) ]

    A_x  B_x  C_x  D_x  A_y  B_y  C_y  D_y
2     1    1    4    1    0    2    0    0
4     1    1    4    1    0    4    4    3
34    3    1    4    4    0    4    4    3
40    0    4    4    3    1    1    4    1
42    0    4    4    3    0    2    0    0
44    0    4    4    3    0    4    4    3
45    0    4    4    3    2    1    1    3
47    0    4    4    3    4    1    2    1
49    0    4    4    3    3    1    0    0

In SQL, I didn't need to create a full cross-join before filtering
away the unwanted matches.  I could incorporate the filtering criteria
as a WHERE clause of a join, essentially in place of an ON clause.
The complex join criterion could involve mathematical or string
functions, or I wrote my own arbitrarily complex functions in VBA (at least I could for
Microsoft Access).
These joins didn't take too much time despite the large number of
records. I strongly suspect that the query engine optimized the execution of the join so that
nothing close to a full cross-join is constructed.
Is there any way to incorporate complex join criteria into pandas
joins without the memory and time requirements of an intermediate
cross-join?  How flexible can the criteria be, e.g., can they
incorporate arbitrary functions, including user defined functions?
Background
The dataframe consists of many messages with various sender IDs.  The
IDs are typed in, so the data is very dirty.  I will use Levenshtein
distance to group together IDs that are likely to be the same, but
each ID needs to be tested against every other ID, even though matches
will only be made between small subsets of the IDs (at least, I hope so).
That is only the starting point for a matching criterion.  The
messages contain travel destinations, various time stamps, and other
identifying data.  The join criterion will be expanded in an exploratory manner to make
use of matching conditions between other fields as well.

If your dataframe is small and the cross join time is insignificant, I'll say leave it as-is.
However, if your dataframe is big and a cross joins blows out the computer's memory, you can use pyjanitor. First install it from pip / conda / poetry / whatever package manager you use:
pip install pyjanitor

The library adds a conditional_join method to the dataframe object:
import janitor

df_in.conditional_join(df_in, ("A", "B", "<"), ("C", "D", ">"))

The syntax is:
left.conditional_join(right, ("col_in_left", "col_in_right", "comparison"))


Thanks, @Code Different.  That's a good starting point for inequalities.  Would you be aware of a solution for when the matching expression contains functions of the key columns, either predefined or (in the ideal case) user-defined?  That's what I will eventually need in order to avoid a full cross-join or rolling my own loops to check each and every possible pair of rows between left and right dataframes. Actually, the expressions will be in terms of scalar values from the key columns.

In that case, you should apply the functions before sending the dataframe(s) into the join. if your function cannot be applied before hand (for example, match when the two rows are within x unit of each other), cross join in the only way. There are techniques to reduce memory usage for such a join when the participating frames are big.

Thanks again, @Code Different.  Unfortunately, for distance-like functions or other functions involving the key fields from the records of both dataframes, the function can't be pre-evaluated for each dataframe in isolation.  (We probably can't even call them key fields anymore because they aren't being equated, they merely feed the distance function).  It makes me wonder how Microsoft access was able to accomplish this without taking forever.

One alternative is to export this to Access and do the join in Access, but that needs a significant detour to finagle the COM interface. Another is to do it in C and become familiar with how this is invoked from Python.  Before doing either, I'm going to delve into past works that make use of similar distances between all data points in a large dataset, then thresholding these distances to determine pairwise matches. In my case, the threshold is adaptive and not uniform across the data set.
This is more algorithmic than coding, so it may be worth an ask at the data science stack exchange.

Sorry for the late reply. The problem you described seemed to be the sargable problem in the DB world. You don't know the distance between 2 points until you have applied the function on them. If the distance function can be vectorized with numpy, the cross join will be fast but memory usage may be an issue (and there are ways to address that). Can you provide some details about the distance function?

It's the Levenshtein distance between text labels.  I found a scalar implementation here. Others have sought a vectorized implementation (e.g., here) but it is said to be unlikely to exist. I also searched for "sargable" and it would be a big detour for me to fully understand it. Regardless of sargability, however, I can't see a way to get around the calculation of approximately $n^2/2$ distances.

I'm not aware of any vectorized Levenshtein implementation. Even if it exists, we are still talking about n^2 / 2 operations, just faster. I've used the textdistance library in the past. See if you can help you with a fast distance function. The looping is perhaps unavoidable.

Thanks.  I guess my bottleneck isn't the exact distance metric so much as a vectorized implementation to mitigate the O(n^2) complexity.  I'll look into textdistance.  For context, I'll but feeding the distances to HDBSCAN to group similar ID labels.

From here, it looks as if the textdistance implementation is slow. I'm also realizing that it is also a scalar implementation, which is in line with your last comment. I may be looking at a C implementation, which means getting to know the interface with Python as well as settting up a C compilation environment, which I haven't touched in many decades.

Furthermore, such external dependencies would likely be platform or OS specific. It seemed cleaner to wrap a Matlab implementation for invocation from Python -- but there doesn't seem to be a vectorized Matlab implementation either.
